# animate.css does not trigger twice in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css

I have a table which I fade in from the left or right depending which content is placed inside. It is created like:

```html
<table id="table" class="centered animated"></table>
```

Whenever I fill it with data, I use the DOM to animate it in (with animate.css):

```js
// This code is executed when the entire table's contents is changed
table.classList.remove('fadeInLeft');
table.classList.remove('fadeInRight');

if (animateFromLeftCondition) { table.classList.add('fadeInRight') }
else if (animateFromRightCondition) { table.classList.add('fadeInLeft') }
```

The animation trigger properly unless I trigger the same animation twice (e.g. I animate from the left twice). When looking in my devtools, I can see that the table's classes are being changed, implying the removal and addition of the `fadeInRight` and `animated` classes is successful. Am I missing something that prevents me from executing the same animation twice in a row?

Comment: You don't want to remove 'animated' class. always keep it with the elements. and just toggle animation classes

Comment: @DracSkywalker I tried that as well but the same issue persists :(

Comment: I'll edit the original post to not include the toggling of the `animation` class to reflect this